# Implementing a collection class to represent a Path of Segments

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement a custom made 2D geometry library. Originally I was looking at the problem of intersections of many circles but wanted to widen the scope of the code to deal with many future geometry based problems.

I already have a vector (2D) class defined. I wish to derive all my other geometrical entities from `Shape`. These will include 0D objects, 1D objects (and 2D objects, though i think this is best achieved through a custom made `IArea` interface supported by for example closed loops (1D objects) and special polygons, figures (i.e. `Circle`)).

In this question I want to focus on the best way to define a 1D Path, but first my definitions for 0D objects.

`Node` will be my 0D base class `Segment` (`Node` to `Node`), `SingleEndSegment` (`Node` to infinity) and `Curve` (no nodes) will be my 1D base classes (I have some misgivings over the best way to define these). The links between `Node`s can be line vectors, circular arcs, any type of curve function really, though initially just lines and circular arcs.

One important point to note hear is that I'd like `Segment` and `SingleEndSegment` to be free from Internal Nodes. Meaning, if I want to add a `Node` along a `Segment`, I need to convert it to two `Segment`s. It's important that if I do this and I have a reference to this object in, say, a `Polygon` (made up of `LineSegment`s derived from `Segment`), then the `Polygon` object takes account of this change. On the other hand, I'd like curves to contain a list of `Node`s along them (i.e. a `Line` has a reference list of its intersections).

Thinking about this now, I am not sure whether to derive the `Segment` classes and `SingleEndSegment` classes from `Curve` classes (i.e. `LineSegment : Line : Shape and ArcSegment : Circle : Shape`) or in my current approach from an abstract `Segment` class. I can't have both without perhaps creating a `Segment` interface.

I will define a `Node` to contain a vector and an ordered `List` of the `Segment`s or `SingleEndSegments` which connect at it:

```
public class Node
{
      private vector m_point;
      private List<Segment> m_links;
}
```

As `Intersection`s of `Circle`s and `Line`s are key to my main geometry focus, I must derive an `Intersection` class from `Node` which also defines the two `Curve`s which pass through it (though they would perhaps also be available through the `Segment`s).

```
public class Intersection : Node
{
      private Curve[] m_curves = new Curve[2];

      //some code
}
```

Now onto the 1D objects (I have `Start` and `End` because I may consider some notion of direction at a later date):

```
    public abstract class Segment : Shape
    {
        private Node m_start;
        private Node m_end;

        public Node Start
        {
            get { return m_start; }
            set { m_start = value; }
        }

        public Node End
        {
            get { return m_end; }
            set { m_end = value; }
        }

        public Segment() : base() 
        { 
            Start = null;
            End = null;
        }

        public Segment(Node s, Node e) : base() 
        {
            Start = s;
            End = e;
        }

   }
```

An example of a derived class would be:

```
  public class LineSegment : Segment 
  {

       private vector m_vector;

       public vector Vec
       {
           get { return m_vector; }
           set { m_vector = value; }
       }
   }
```

Note that in my current implementation I have a vector whereas, I could have `LineSegment` contain a `Line` (which naturally possesses the vector of its direction).

But I'd also like to have a derived abstract class called `IntersectionSegment` between two known intersection points (to be the base of `IntersectionLineSegment`). I could do this as follows, but would ideally prefer to deal with the `Node`s being Intersections in a better way. How can I best do that?

```
    public abstract class IntersectionSegment : Segment
    {
        private Intersection m_inters_start;

        public Intersection Start
        {
            get { return m_inters_start; }
            set { m_inters_start = value; }
        }
    }
```

Not ideal.

Now the main trouble I'm having comes in defining a `Path` as a collection of `Segment`s:

```
public class Path<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Segment
 {
    private List<T> segments = new List<T>();
    public List<T> Segments 
    {  
        set { segments = value;}
        get { return this.segments; } 
    }

    public T this[int pos]
    {
        get { return (T)segments[pos]; }
        set { segments[pos] = value; }
    }

    public Path()
    {
      this.Segments = new List<T>();   
    }

    public Path(List<T> s)
    {
        this.Segments = s;
    }

    public void AddSegment(T s) {Segments.Add(s);}

    public int Count {get {return Segments.Count;}}

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    { return Segments.GetEnumerator();}
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { return Segments.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

I'm having major problems working out how to define derived types from this `Path` and how to use this generic Path in an efficient way.

One key method I wish to implement is an `Intersection` (method here not 0D object defined above) of say a `Line` with a (closed) `Path`. I'll need to check the `Intersection` with all `Segment`s and I'd like to under certain conditions replace a `Segment` within a `Path` with a `LineSegment` and an altered version of the existing `Segment`, maintaining the order of the `Path` `Segment`s.

Comment: Consider using auto-properties with `get; private set;` in the `Segment` class. I would also chain constructors like so: `public Segment() : this(s: null, e: null)`. Finally, can you post at least the signature of the methods that you need to create? Not many people will read this question in its entirety.

Comment: Just a question, Have you looked at WPF? Path in the WPF is not sufficient for what you need? I am just asking so we don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is a heck of a project. Take a look at the implementation of the Asymptote language / tool. http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=120000

Answer (score 1):

First of all I really would like to have a good computational library in C#, will be your OS?
Anyway my two cents:

- I really appreciate the fact you are considering circular segmants to
  ( arcs ), if you manage to use it properly everywere (
  distance/intersection, offseting ) this would be great.
- I'm not sure I want all the object in that library deriving from shape, leave object for the algorithms, try to keep the geometrics entities as small as possible
- The pat too, leave it as an entity apart. It will be something like a linked list ( leveraging the fact the end point of a single segment is necessarily the start of the next one ) and differentiate each segment type ( line, arc ) with a plain old enum. This probably will sound as a not good OOP, but trust me it will pay back much more.